# По стандарту html, в ul можно вложить только списки li?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

По стандарту html w3c в ul на первом уровне вложенности могут быть только списки li? Или можно вложить любой другой элемент и это не будет ошибкой? Просто случайно заметил что у меня в коде в ul вложен div как заголовок списка и потом уже идёт li. Загуглил, ничего про этот момент не нашел

Comment: Короче в ul вставляете li, а в li уже суйте что хотите. Я обычно сую туда span и задаю ему display: block, если нужно сформировать что-то блочное, а не простой текст вставить.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#technical_summary «Permitted content: Zero or more `<li>`, `<script>` and `<template>` elements.»

Answer (score 1):

Только `li`.

А чтобы проверить, будет что-то ошибкой или нет, надо вставить разметку в [w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Comment: Если script и template =) Не знаю уж зачем template.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а style?

Comment: Вообще-то формально нет https://caninclude.glitch.me/caninclude?child=Style&parent=Ul хотя браузеры конечно распарсят и применят